# How to remove or hide the server list in Swagger UI using Springdoc?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

How to disable or hide the "Servers" dropdown from Swagger UI?

[image: Swagger UI server dropdown]

My Maven dependency is:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId> 
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId> 
  <version>1.6.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply don't define servers... ?

Comment: Hi @DavidAnsermot im not defining any swagger servers.

Comment: To hide or remove the "Servers" dropdown from Swagger UI when using Springdoc in a Spring Boot application, you can configure the OpenAPI definition to not include any servers. By default, Springdoc adds a server entry based on the URL from which the documentation is served. If you provide an empty list of servers, the "Servers" dropdown will not be displayed in the Swagger UI. Maybe this will be useful: https://medium.com/@moh.hasan.muktasyim.billah/modify-swagger-to-show-dynamic-api-based-on-config-using-springdoc-openapi-647309280a29

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have the same problem and I found out that unfortunately it is hardcoded. The only thing you can do is overwrite url to display something else or to just be empty.

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

@Bean
public OpenAPI config() {
    return new OpenAPI()
            .addServersItem(serverInfo());
}

private Server serverInfo() {
    return new Server()
            .url("");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a older question but nevertheless.

You can set servers to be empty list, but you also need to set 1 server, because if you refresh without it, server list will appear again. You can do it with annotation.

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(
    info = @Info(title = "API", version = "v1.0.0"),
    servers = {@Server(url = "", description = "foo")})
public class OpenAPIConfig {

@Bean
public OpenApiCustomiser hideServers() {
    return openApi -> {
        openApi.setServers(new ArrayList<>());
    };
}
```

}

Note that you need to set either url or description for it to work, you can't leave it empty.

I know this is not the question, but if you also want to hide top bar, you can do it by specifying springdoc.swagger-ui.layout=BaseLayout in application.properties, even though it says in documentation it is default.